# Difference Matrix in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, vector

What is the most efficient/easiest way to create a matrix that is the difference between 2 already defined matrices? For example, suppose the matrices are something like:

```
[1, 5, 9] [1, 5, 9] [1, 5, 9]
```

and

```
[5, 5, 5] [3, 3, 3] [7, 7, 7]
```

In this case, I'd want the result:

```
[-4, 0, 4] [-2, 2, 6] [-6, -2, 2]
```

I'm used to Matlab, where you could simply do `matrix1 - matrix2`.

Comment: Post an example! Are the matrixes of the same dimension?

Comment: Yes, they were of the same dimension.
Suppose the matrices are something like
[1, 5, 9]
[1, 5, 9]
[1, 5, 9]
and
[5, 5, 5]
[3, 3, 3]
[7, 7, 7]
In this case, I'd want the result
[-4, 0, 4]
[-2, 2, 6]
[-6, -2, 2]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a library, [math.js](http://mathjs.org) seems to have a pretty elegant (although admittedly not identical to MATLAB) way to do this:

> Subtract two values, x - y. For matrices, the function is evaluated element wise.
>
> `math.subtract(x, y)`

(source: http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/subtract.html)

Here's an example using math.js and the numbers you gave: https://jsfiddle.net/chonfkmd/

In pure javascript, you might be stuck with a `for` loop. Let me know if you need pure js and I can see what I can do.